# Flask-SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many with composite key

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a Many-to-Many relationship using Flask-SQLAlchemy using two primary keys from one model and one from another. My models are the following:

Service:

```
class Service(db.Model):
    """
        Service model object
    """
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
```

ContactClosure:

```
class ContactClosure(db.Model):

    module = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    relay = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

    #Relationships
    hostname = db.Column(db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('ip2cc.hostname'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    device_name = db.Column(db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('device.name'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    services = db.relationship('Service', secondary=cc_services, backref=db.backref('contact_closures', lazy='dynamic'))
```

This is the related table:

```
cc_services = db.Table('cc_services',
                    db.Column('service_name', db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('service.name')),
                    db.Column('hostname', db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('contact_closure.hostname')),
                    db.Column('device_name', db.String(120), db.ForeignKey('contact_closure.device_name')),
                    )
```

And this is the error I am getting:

> "AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between
>   parent/child tables on relationship ContactClosure.services - there
>   are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table
>   'cc_services'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list
>   of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key
>   reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child
>   tables."

If anybody can tell what is the problem here I will be highly thankful, I've been stuck on this for a while...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finally I found the solution to this problem:

```
cc_services = db.Table('cc_services',
    db.Column('service_name', db.String(120),
    db.ForeignKey('service.name')),
    db.Column('cc_hostname', db.String(120)),
    db.Column('cc_module', db.Integer),
    db.Column('cc_relay', db.Integer),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(
        ('cc_hostname', 'cc_module', 'cc_relay'),
        ('contact_closure.hostname', 'contact_closure.module', 'contact_closure.relay')
    )
)
```

If a model has multiple keys, they must be declared on the helper table on a ForeignKeyConstraint statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 'foreign_keys' argument as the error text says, like this:

```
services = db.relationship('Service', secondary=cc_services, backref=db.backref('contact_closures', lazy='dynamic'), foreign_keys=[column_name])
```

Comment: If I add this:
`services = db.relationship('Service', secondary=cc_services, backref=db.backref('contact_closures', lazy='dynamic'),
                               foreign_keys=[hostname, device_name])`

 I get this other error 

"NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ContactClosure.services - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'cc_services'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions."

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an association table or fully declared table metadata, you can use the `primary_key=True` in both columns, as suggested [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/ormconfiguration.html).

Association table example:

```
employee_role = db.Table(
    "employee_role",
    db.Column("role_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("role.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("employee_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("agent.id"), primary_key=True),
)
```

Metadata example:

```
# this is using SQLAlchemy
class EmployeeRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee_role"

    role_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

# this is using Flask-SQLAlchemy with factory pattern, db gives you access to all SQLAlchemy stuff
class EmployeeRole(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "employee_role"

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Alembic migration for it:

```
op.create_table(
        'employee_role',
        sa.Column('role_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('employee_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('role_id', 'employee_id')
    )
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE agent_role (
    role_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (role_id, employee_id)
);
```

In terms of relationship, declare it on one side (this should give you `role.employees` or `employee.roles` which should return a `list`):

```
# this is using Flask-SQLAlchemy with factory pattern, db gives you access to all SQLAlchemy stuff
class Employee(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    roles = db.relationship("Role", secondary=employee_role, backref="employee")
```

Your Role class can be:

```
# this is using Flask-SQLAlchemy with factory pattern, db gives you access to all SQLAlchemy stuff
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "role"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False, unique=True)
```